# Block access to php.ini and phpinfo.php in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

I read another question on how to do this, and the most highlighted solution was the following:

```
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I can't really fiddle with this without knowing for sure, since I don't have any testing environment or anything.

My question is, can I add multiple files to the same rule for denying access? What would the formatting be to add additional files to the same deny rule above?

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the more important question is why would you have php.ini and a phpinfo file in a web accessible directory in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible for me to move them without affecting my main website in the root? And could it be any folder?

Comment: I am not sure how your server is configured, so it would be hard to say.  Certainly you can simply removed the phpinfo.php file if all it is doing is giving you the typical phpinfo page. I am just not sure why a php.ini file would ever be in the web directory or whether that is just a copy of the ini file and not even in use. You can certailny look on that phpinfo page to determine what the what the Configuration File path is. If it is not your web root, then you should be able to safely delete it (make a copy in another directory before you do though.)

Comment: I'm using Bluehost, so it's inside public_html. I'm unsure if they're the actual files creating the functions, but based on some previous encounters with them, I don't think they are. I'll take a look now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Ahh ... some kind of shared host environment... might as well throw security out the window :P

Comment: Indeed, but I can try my best to make it less awful than it is by default.

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple files with the same rule? That's not a good idea for performance. All the rules can be included in the ini file in public_html. In cPanel you can block access to directories and files, maybe you should check if that is possible in your Bluehost account. I am pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions [per the manual entry for `<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files), or [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch):

```
<FilesMatch "/(phpinfo\.php|php\.ini)">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```